# Documenting a public concrete variant of a private generic type

Tags: generics, rust, access-modifiers, rustdoc

In [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70102943/857390), I asked how to publicly expose only a concrete variant (`Foo<u32>`) of a private generic type (`Foo<T>`). The suggested solution is as follows:

```rust
mod internal {
    /// Private documentation of `Foo`.
    pub struct Foo<X> {
        /// Private documentation of `x`.
        pub x: X,
    }

    impl Foo<u32> {
        pub fn foo() -> u32 {
            32
        }
    }

    impl Foo<u8> {
        pub fn foo() -> u8 {
            8
        }
    }
}

/// Public documentation of `FooBar`.
pub type FooBar = internal::Foo<u32>;
```

This works, in the sense that the public API just contains `FooBar`, but not `Foo`. However, it is lacking from a documentation point of view. Here's the output of `cargo doc` for `FooBar`:

---

[image: Screenshot of Cargo documentation]

---

As you can see,

- The private type `Foo` appears in the documentation, but it's not a link and `Foo` gets no separate
- Neither the private documentation of `Foo`, nor that of `Foo.x` is shown

As a result, this documentation is not really useful. Obviously I could add more information to the documentation of `FooBar`, but that still would not make the documentation of `FooBar` look like that of a regular `struct`.

With this approach, the documentation of `FooBar` is clearly inferior to the "equivalent" definition of `FooBar` like this:

```rust
/// Public documentation of `FooBar`.
pub struct FooBar {
    /// Public documentation of `x`.
    x: u32,
}
```

I've put "equivalent" into quotes because I do assume that from the compiler's point of view (and obviously that of `cargo doc`), these two definitions of `FooBar` are quite different. My issue is that readers of my documentation should not have to care about that difference.

**Is there a way to achieve the "natural" documentation in this situation?**

I'm happy to use a completely different approach for hiding the generic `Foo` definition if that's necessary.

Comment: that why I disagree about this trick, Rust pub visibility rules are not perfect, you use a trick to give user a public type but it's a private type, that wrong, your type should be all pub to start with if user are expected to need a doc for it. Tl;DR: semver trick sux and hurt user, just make pub item pub as they should be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate documentation for private items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136276/how-to-generate-documentation-for-private-items)

Comment: @Stargateur: As I've said, I'm open to completely different approaches. However, note that the types in my real use case are significantly more complex, so reducing boilerplate and code duplication is important to me.

Comment: @Stargateur: Also, thanks for the suggested duplicate. I don't think it matches my question, since I'm trying to document a *public* type.

Comment: In the given example, field `x` is private—so why do you want it to appear in the documentation?

Comment: @eggyal: That was an error in the code I posted, I've corrected it to make `x` public. That doesn't change the output of `cargo doc`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @FlorianBrucker Rust is a verbose language.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker "since I'm trying to document a public type" no you are not, that as I said, the trick you use is bad, it's neither a public neither a private item, it's a private type leak, as I say I would prefer such code don't compile. I'm not 100% sure but I believe if you use document private item you will see the documentation thus answering your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#[cfg(doc)]` to fake the item:

```rust
#[cfg(not(doc))]
pub type FooBar = internal::Foo<u32>;
#[cfg(doc)]
/// Public documentation of `FooBar`.
pub struct FooBar {
    /// Public documentation of `x`.
    pub x: u32,
}
```

But this will hide all `impl`s (unless you'll copy them too) and duplicate code. So, don't do that.